# Proper material for testing capacitor at 105°C

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

I've built a circuit to estimate capacitors life. I need to test it at 105°C. I have no idea which material to use for the chamber that I want to put my capacitor in and control the temperature.

Comment: Just about any lab oven or environmental chamber will easily handle that temperature.. if you are trying to do it on the cheap, consumer cooking appliances can be modified to work at a lower range by adding a PID controller and scaling back the power via various means

Comment: a small box containing an incandescent lamp, controlled by a dimmer

Answer (score 0):

Get an old kitchen oven. The temperature regulation nay not be too precise, but you can add an industrial controller and thermocouple. Or spend big money and get a proper thermal test chamber.

Comment: You also need to add some thermal mass, otherwise it wont work.